# How do you delete an iFolder from iFolder admin interface

Tags: linux

There are only two buttons at the bottom of the screen "enable" and "disable". When I check the box next to an iFolder one of them is lit (depending on what the state of the folder is)... but there is no button to delete the folder (as it seems there should be from the documentation). There is a delete button in the "orphaned" tab but how do you "orphan" an iFolder?

I'm logged in to the admin interface as admin, who is currently the owner of the folder I wish to delete.

Comment: Is this the iFolder software you're referring to? http://www.kablink.org/ifolder

Comment: Yes. Novell iFolder software:  http://ifolder.com/ifolder